# Python error intents missing how can i fix?

Tags: python, error-handling, roblox

Hello Im having This Error and idk how can i fix it

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 11, in <module>
    blox = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'
```

And on Linke 11 my code wrriten is -

```
blox = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the keyword argument `intents` to the `Bot` constructor.

`blox = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)`

But first you have to initialize the `intents` variable. You can read more about `intents` [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html?highlight=intents).